# Java/C# Serial port write to Arduino reading wrong bytes

Tags: java, c#, serial-port, arduino

I have a program I wrote originally in Java that writes to a serial port that I have an arduino pro mini plugged into. Each chunk of data is 6 bytes, and when the arduino receivies the data, it just spits it back out to the console to I can see that. The problem is when the data is spit back out, it is often in the wrong order with some bytes appearing to be sent twice. I wrote the same functionality in c# and the same thing is happening. I wrote some arduino code to write data to itself and echo it back, and that is correct.

So the problem must be my non arduino code, or some hardware settings. In my code, I added a delay after every write that allows the data to stay correct for a while, but it eventually starts getting screwed up.

I tried messing with the baud rate, but it didn't help. Why could this be happening??

Here's my arduino code.

```
//wait for seven bytes to come
if (Serial.available() >= 7) {
    /* read the most recent byte */
   Serial.print("Data: ");
   //set the enable byte
   data[0] = ENABLE;
   Serial.print((int)data[0], DEC);
   Serial.print(" ");
   for(int i = 1; i < DATA_SIZE; i++)
    {
      data[i] = Serial.read();
        Serial.print((int)data[i], DEC);
        Serial.print(" ");
     }

     Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a delay() in the main loop? Maybe the loop() function cycle to fast for the Serial communication...

Comment: I've tried that after I'm done reading. I also tried adding Serial.flush(). Nothing helped.